# what to do about .ssh-agent pop up at login screen?

Tags: 12.04, ssh, git, bashrc, ssh-agent

I was setting up git with a ssh key passphrase on Ubuntu 12.04 via the terminal with the assistance of [Help.GitHub](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/): "You can run ssh-agent automatically when you open bash by adding the following to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file"  I added the ~/.bashrc file:

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "$SSH_ENV"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "$SSH_ENV"
    . "$SSH_ENV" > /dev/null
    ssh-add
}

# test for identities
function test_identities {
    # test whether standard identities have been added to the agent already
    ssh-add -l | grep "The agent has no identities" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        ssh-add
        # $SSH_AUTH_SOCK broken so we start a new proper agent
        if [ $? -eq 2 ];then
            start_agent
        fi
    fi
}

# check for running ssh-agent with proper $SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]; then
    ps -ef | grep "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    test_identities
    fi
# if $SSH_AGENT_PID is not properly set, we might be able to load one from
# $SSH_ENV
else
    if [ -f "$SSH_ENV" ]; then
    . "$SSH_ENV" > /dev/null
    fi
    ps -ef | grep "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | grep -v grep | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        test_identities
    else
        start_agent
    fi
fi
```

A little later I restarted my computer.  Now, whenever I attempt to log on (i.e. enter my password and press enter at the login screen) as the sole user (as opposed to guest) the screen goes black and a pop-up appears asking me for my `/.ssh/rsa_id passphrase`.

When I enter the passphrase I entered for GitHub, Ubuntu throws me back to the login screen, square one. The only way I know how else to login functionally is as a guest.

What has happened and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: So you're saying when you enter your passphrase, it actually crashes and logs you out entirely? That sounds like a bug. (FWIW, I believe ssh-agent starts automatically)